# MySQL query into XML via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml

I have this PHP for my coursework and I want to use server-side programming to dynamically produce in XML format the pending orders with order details of two tables. When I try to run this I get an error (below) and I believe it comes from the query. I'm and newbie and can't figure it out. Some help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

> XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location:
>   hxxp://xxxx/xxxx/pending_details.php Line Number 2, Column 1:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("eshop");


$query = "select product.name,order_details.quantity, order.date from product.id inner join order on order_details.order_id=order.id inner join product on order_details.product_id=product.id inner join customer on order.cust_id=costumer.id WHERE order.pending=>1";
$res = mysql_query($query);


$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('pendings');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $xml->startElement("order");

    $xml->writeAttribute('name', $row['product.name']);
    $xml->writeAttribute('quantity', $row['order_details.quantity']);
    $xml->writeAttribute('date', $row['order.date']);
    $xml->writeAttribute('pending', $row['order.pending']);

    $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();

header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to access to the row only with the name like this

```
$xml->writeAttribute('name', $row['name']);
$xml->writeAttribute('quantity', $row['quantity']);
$xml->writeAttribute('date', $row['date']);
$xml->writeAttribute('pending', $row['pending']);
```

Comment: output your content with print_r($row) and post it!